# Java generics bound mismatch recursive type

Tags: java, generics

I'm having a weird problem I don't understand how to solve.
Here is the declaration of the class in which the error is appearing:

```
public class DList<V extends Comparable<V>> { ...
```

Down below I have a method which has the following signature:

```
public DList<DList<V>> split(int steps) { ...
```

which gives me the specific error

```
Bound mismatch: The type DList<V> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <V extends Comparable<V>> of the type DList<V>
```

So far the problem is the following class accepts type V which has an upper limit of Comparable, but the recursive type DList isn't accepted.
How can I solve this sort of 'recursion' of types and get rid of the error?

Comment: Um... *what* are you doing here?  Do you really expect your method result to be a `DList` of `DList`s?  Why doesn't `DList` then implement `Comparable`?

Comment: DList stands for an implementation of a double linked list, this method returns a list of lists of the same type based on steps which indicate the size of each list. For instance having a list of [1,2,3,6,1] and step 2, i'm returning lists which have objects [1,2] [3,6] [1]

Comment: Fair.  But why then wouldn't `DList` also implement `Comparable` if you want to use it in this fashion?

Comment: you're absolutely right, what have I been thinking, that's stupid of me, thank you!

Comment: So can we call this question a "typo", close it and move on then? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `DList` implement `Comparable`:

```
public class DList<V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparable<DList<V>> {
    @Override public int compareTo(DList<V> other) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

then make sure that the substitute for `V` is well bounded:

```
public class Other {

    public static <X extends Comparable<X>> DList<DList<X>> split(int steps) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner no :-) `list` would have to be an instance of `Other` (and a superfluous one at that, since `split` is declared static). if you want `split` as a non-static method in `DList`, just declare it as `public DList<DList<V>> split(int steps)` - `V` then will be the same `V` as in the class declaration